# Prolog help | how come 'tony' is true when it should be false?

Tags: list, prolog

From the facts I have, 'tony' should not be true for `pass(tony)`, but I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

I have an atom `pass(Student)` that passes if a Student has the following: their mark in programming > 29, they haven't failed an exam/none of their exam scores < 30, and if their average score for all their exams > 39

I also have an ERROR `No permission to modify static procedure 'length/2'`. I don't know what this is referring to but I would appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction.

I won't include all the facts, but here is an example of a student's:

```
coursework(tony, 57).
programming(tony, 65).
e1(tony, 20).
e2(tony, 80).
e3(tony, 90).
marks(tony, [20, 80, 90]).
```

```
length([], 0).
length([_|Tail], List + 1):-
  length(Tail, List).

sum([], 0).
sum([X|Tail], Sum):-
  sum(Tail, Temp),
  Sum = Temp + X.

avg(List, Avg):-
  sum(List, Sum),
  length(List, Length),
  Length > 0,
  Avg is Sum / Length.

examFail(Student):-
  e1(Student, Mark),
  Mark < 30;
  e2(Student, Mark),
  Mark < 30;
  e3(Student, Mark),
  Mark < 30.

pass(Student):-
  programming(Student, Mark),
  Mark > 29,
  \+ examFail(Mark),
  marks(Student, List),
  avg(List, Avg),
  Avg > 39.
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the title, `Tony` can neither be true nor false, `Tony` is a variable because it starts with a capital letter.

> I have an atom pass(Student)

`pass(Student)` is a predicate, not an atom. An atom is a stringy thing like `a` or `tony`. A predicate can indeed yield *true* or *false*.

> I also have an ERROR No permission to modify static procedure 'length/2'.

This is because you try to define

> ```
> length([], 0).
> length([_|Tail], List + 1):-
>  length(Tail, List).
> ```

But `length/2` is a predicate that is built-in, to determine/set/check the length of a list No redefining allowed!

Evaluation is not done like this:

> ```
> Sum = Temp + X.
> ```

This is unification ("The syntactic structures left and right shall be the same"). You want `is`:

> ```
> Sum is Temp + X.
> ```

Which is correctly use here btw:

> ```
> Avg is Sum / Length.
> ```

For example:

```
sum_list(L,Out) :-
   sum_list(L,0,Out).

sum_list([],R,R).

sum_list([X|Xs],Rrun,Rfin) :-
   Rnex is Rrun + X,
   sum_list(Xs,Rnex,Rfin).
```

This ain't gonna work:

> ```
> examFail(Student):-
>  e1(Student, Mark),
>  Mark < 30;
>  e2(Student, Mark),
>  Mark < 30;
>  e3(Student, Mark),
>  Mark < 30.
> ```

`Mark` is always the same "thing" in this whole clause. The above says that the `Student` must have the same `Mark` in all exams, and that `Mark` must be less than 30. This inequality is redundantly tested 2 more times. Use different variable names:

```
examFail(Student):-
  (e1(Student, MarkE1), MarkE1 < 30);
  (e2(Student, MarkE2), MarkE2 < 30);
  (e3(Student, MarkE3), MarkE3 < 30).
```

Or even better, if data were stored in a more "normal form" (as in RDBMS):

```
marks(e1, tony, 20).
marks(e2, tony, 80).
marks(e3, tony, 90).
```

then one can use [library(aggregate)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)

```
examFail(Student):- aggregate(min(M), marks(_,tony,M), Min), Min<20.
```

(I think, need to test)

This ain't gonna work either:

> ```
> pass(Student):-
>   programming(Student, Mark),
>   Mark > 29,
>   \+ examFail(Mark),
>   marks(Student, List),
>   avg(List, Avg),
>   Avg > 39.
> ```

You call `examFail(Mark)`. That should be `examFail(Student)`.

Comment: Thanks man for your help so far; I am gonna work on sorting it out. As you can tell, I am pretty new to this, so there are quite a few minor errors. For `examFail(Marks)`, that is just an example of me not reading the code.

Comment: @zfac122 Sure. Good hunting!